# How do we differentiate between subspaces of same dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Consider a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ with $\dim{V}=n\ge2$. 
Consider two subspaces $S_1$ and $S_2$.
Additionally, let $A$ be the matrix formed by basis vectors of $S_1$ acting as columns of $A$. Similarly, let $B$ be the matrix formed by basis vectors of $S_2$ acting as columns of $B$.

According to my understanding (knowledge),

1. $A\overset{r}\equiv B\iff N(A)=N(B)$.
2. RRE form of $A=$ RRE form of $B\iff S_1=S_2$, i.e., $S1$ and $S_2$ span the same subspace.

My main doubt is, under what conditions statement $1\implies$ statement $2$ ?

and under what conditions statement $2\implies$ statement $1$ ? 
Please show counter-examples, wherever necessary.

Also tell, how do we differentiate between $S_1$ and $S_2$ when $S_1\neq S_2$ but $\dim{S_1}=\dim{S_2}$. (Which property like rank/nullity or something else make them different? )

The premise here is that there exist subspaces having same dimension, but different set of vectors.

**Remark:** $N(A)$ denotes null-space of matrix $A$ and
$A\overset{r}\equiv B$ means $A$ is row-equivalent to $B$.

Comment: Consider, for example, $S_1=\{(a,a)\}:a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $S_2=\{(a,0):a\in\mathbb{R}\}$.  
Here $\dim{S_1}=\dim{S_2}$, but $S_1\neq S_2$.

Comment: What does "RRE" stand for? Reduced row echelon?

Comment: @DeapSoup, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a grain of salt as Linear Algebra isn't my forte, but I think statement 1 and 2 are equivalent, as A and B's rowspaces span the same subspace iff they have the same RRE